# Does not implement interface member issues

Tags: c#, interface

I have:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string test { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
[DataContract]
public class TestGeneric : ITest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string test;
}
```

But i keep getting the error: `'TestGeneric' does not implement interface member 'ITest.Test'` on `TestGeneric` in the `public class TestGeneric : ITest` line of code. Would someone be able to explain why this is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have created a field, as you omitted the `{ get; set; }` accessors that make a member a property.

The implementation must match the interface exactly, so add those accessors:

```
public class TestGeneric : ITest
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and clear explanation. That makes perfect sense!