# Compiler Error CS0535, When using Azure bot framework

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot

First of all I'm using C# with Azure bot framework to get my bot to greet the user (sent the first message), but when I enter the required code I receive a string of CS0535 errors.

This is my C# code:

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
        // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
        // Not available in all channels

        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        Activity reply = message.CreateReply("Hello from my simple Bot!");
        connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
    {
        // Handle add/remove from contact lists
        // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
    {
        // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
    }
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

And these are the errors I receive:

```
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.BaseUri' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.SerializationSettings' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.DeserializationSettings' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.Credentials' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.Attachments' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Controllers\MessagesController.cs(14,120): error CS0535: 'ConnectorClient' does not implement interface member 'IConnectorClient.Conversations' [D:\home\site\wwwroot\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\wwwroot\.\Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\wwwroot\.\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So is `ConnectorClient` your class, or one provided with the bot framework?

Comment: is the error something related to what is discussed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826391/does-not-implement-interface-member-issues

Comment: @DaisyShipton yes the Connector client is one provided by the bot framework `public class ConnectorClient : Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient>, IDisposable, Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IConnectorClient{}`

Comment: @Fuzzybear No I do not think this is related, I am just trying to get the bot to display a message at the very beginning of the chat (before the user has a chance to).

Comment: Did you try in bot emulator?

Comment: Have you updated all the nuget packages and double checked there is not an old dll somewhere?

Comment: @user1515791 Could you expand on your answer please? I dont think I have done what you have mentioned

Comment: I guess you used NuGet to get the Microsoft.Bot.Connector etc dlls? If so, there are frequent updates and maybe there is a mismatch between the references and the actual dlls used. So, make sure you got all right dlls and updated as well. Maybe even start a new solution, just to install the correct packages, check it builds and from there, working your way back.